# How can we solve differential equation for $\nu(r)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

How can we find $\nu(r)$?
$$
\frac{d}{dr}\left(\nu'(r)e^{\lambda(r)}\right) 
=
2 C^2\, e^{\nu(r)-\lambda(r)} 
$$
with 
$$
e^\lambda = r^2+C_1 r+ C_2
$$
where $C, C_1, C_2$ are constants. If $C=0$ then 
$$
\nu(r) = C_3 \int \frac{dr}{r^2+C_1 r+ C_2}
$$
but in the case when $C\neq 0$, it is a bit difficult.

Answer (score 2):

*"a bit difficult"* seems to be a true understatement !

It is more pleasant writing $e^\lambda=(r-a)(r-b)$ which makes the differential equation to be
$$(r-a) (r-b) \nu ''+(2r-(a+b)) \nu '-\frac{2 C^2 e^{\nu }}{(r-a) (r-b)}=0$$

At this point, I am totally stuck and cheating (shame on me ?), I used a CAS which produces (assuming $C\neq 0$)
$$\nu=\log \left(K_1 \left(\tan ^2\left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{K_1} \left(K_2\pm\frac{2 C }{a-b}\log
   \left(\frac{r-b}{r-a}\right)\right)\right)+1\right)\right)$$

The most funny is that, knowing this answer, I tried to use $\nu=\log(\mu)$ whcih lead to an awful differential equation for which the CAS gave up.

Now, have fun !

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Problem is that If you put $C=0$ then you have $\nu -const$. But it should be $$ \nu(r) = C_3\int \frac{dr}{r^2+C_1 r+C_2}=\frac{2C_3}{\sqrt{4 C_2-C_1^2}} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{C_1+2 r}{\sqrt{4 C_2-C_1^2}}\right)$$ which is not constant.

Comment: @Bturimov. I wrote : *assuming* $C\neq 0$. Otherwise, as you wrote, the problem is totally different. In fact, I forgot to add $a\neq b$. Do you enjoy the monster ? Cheers :-)

Comment: I am not surprising from your answer,  No problem will not change if you take $C=0$, answer should same in both cases, a) Integrate first and put $C=0$, b) put $C=0$ and then integrate.

Comment: @Bturimov. Not at all, be sure !

Comment: At least when take limit you have to reduce result when $C=0$. That I have shared this problem here. Some thing strange here.

Comment: Simple example: $$\nu(r) = C_3 \int \frac{dr}{r^2+C_1r+C_2} = \frac{2C_3}{\sqrt{4 C_2-C_1^2}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{C_1+2 r}{\sqrt{4 C_2-C_1^2}}\right)$$ Assume that $C_1=0$ then $$\nu(r) = C_3 \int \frac{dr}{r^2+C_2} = \frac{2C_3}{2\sqrt{C_2}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{C_2}}\right)$$ or in the case when $C_2=0$, we get $$\nu(r) = -\frac{C_3}{C_1}Log(1+C_1/r)$$ in both cases a) and b)

Comment: @Bturimov  Claude Leibovici's solution reduces to a constant because the constant solution is a solution to your equation when $C=0$. The solution for the case $C=0$ you give is incomplete because it does not include the constant solution.  Claude Leibovici's solution in the case $C\neq 0$ is correct. One can verify it directly.

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I agree with the solution you give in the case $C\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. No, I don't think so. Please have a look at problem carefuly: $(\nu'(r)e^{\lambda(r)})' = 2C^2 e^{\nu(r)-\lambda(r)}$ and put $C=0$ then you get $\nu(r)=C_3\int \frac{dr}{r^2+C_1 r+C_2}=...$ which is not constant. For $C\neq 0$ case you can integrate directly or you can use some program like Claude Leibovici did and you will get some result, and then put $C=0$ in your result you will get some constant. If you agree with Claude Leibovici then you have to explain this paradox.

Comment: @Bturimov Take your differential equation, the very first one. Put $C=0$ in it. Then $v(r)=constant$ is a solution because when $v(r)=constant$, then $v'(r)=0$. It is trivial to check.

Comment: @Bturimov When you write the solution as an indefinite integral, there is an integration constant. This integration constant is the constant solution. When you performed the integral, you did not include the constant of integration. For example the correct answer for $\int x dx$ is not $^2/2$ but rather $^2/2+$, where $$ is a free constant.